# Workaround for Facebook Graph Search for user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I've searched and can't find any recent questions that are relevant.

The Facebook Graph Search API call to search for users has been deprecated since last year, and no longer works. See this bug report:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/453298034751100?browse=search_516534c213df06064266897

All the existing questions I can find on Stackoverflow which address user searching predate this bug report, so none of them have any useful answers now.

So my question is, has anyone found a reliable workaround for this? Is there any other way of automated searching for users on Facebook by either name or public email address?

Comment: What do you need it for? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to reinstate a feature which was previously available, and which our users found helpful.

Comment: The context is a web-based app which mimics core Facebook functionality via the API and allows access to those functions without needing to be logged into Facebook, thus circumventing restrictive policies which prevent access to Facebook directly.  A kind of "Facebook-lite", so to speak.

All of this has been implemented via the API and is fully compliant with FB's AUP. So I don't want workarounds which involve things like screenscraping, as that would break the AUP and threaten the future of the app. But I do want to reinstate some features which users liked but have been lost.